# Adding item-permissions on ListItem synchronously on EventReceiver in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, event-receiver

I need to set Item-Permissions on creation of an Item in a SharePoint-List. Therefor I created an EventReceiver

Inside the *ItemAdded*-Event I can get the ListItem (properties.ListItem) but that Event is fired **asynchronously**.

On the other Side I have the **synchronous** Event *ItemAdding*. But inside this Event the ListItem does not exist so I cannot add Userpermissions.

Is there a way to solve this dilemma?

Comment: What dilemma ? Use the Item-Added event; if your question is how to setting event handler sync you can specify the sync / async on element.xml of the event receiver. You can also use a simple workflow with action "run the action as user" or something like that and inside use the set permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Item added event receiver. Edit the Elements.xml file of the event receiver and set the `synchronization` element as below..

```
<Synchronization>Synchronous</Synchronization>
```

Comment: Did not expect it to be that simple... :D Thanks